# Update a column in a table with query results

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have an output table `EngFilterlbl` populated with data to print out a label, all except the serial number :

```
partnum,comments, freq_rate, labelnum, job, serial_num
-------------------------------------------------------
345                100mghz       1     4567  
345                100mghz       2     4567
345                100mgzh       3     4567
```

I have a query result to grab the serial number from the other tables

```
track_num,item,ref_num,ref_line_suf,ser_num
--------------------------------------------
 123       345    4567     0         9991
 123       345    4567     0         9992
 123       345    4567     0         9993
```

I need to get the serial number into EngFilterlbl the order of the serial numbers doesn't matter.

The code for the query result is

```
select 
    matltrack_mst.track_num,item, ref_num, ref_line_suf,  ser_num
from 
    matltrack_mst
left outer join 
    ser_track_mst on ser_track_mst.track_num = matltrack_mst.track_num 
                  and ser_track_mst.site_ref = matltrack_mst.site_ref
where 
    ref_num = @job  and ref_line_suf = @suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

In the update statement,  You can use `inner join` between EngFilterlbl  table and other tables from where you get the ser_num. like below -

```
update eng -- this will indicate to update EngFilterlbl table
set eng.serial_num = mtm.ser_num -- I assume ser_num is part of matltrack_mst table, so used mtm alias
from EngFilterlbl eng
  inner join matltrack_mst mtm on mtm.ref_num = eng.job
  Left outer join ser_track_mst stm on stm.track_num = mtm.track_num 
                                and stm.site_ref = mtm.site_ref
where 
   ref_line_suf = @suffix
```